# How do I select AF-C on a Nikon D5500?

Tags: continuous-autofocus, nikon-d5500

How do I enable the AF-C option on my Nikon D5500? When I go into Focus Mode, I get two choices: AF-A and MF. All the books and online tutorials say there should be an option for AF-C on this camera model, but it's simply not there and I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the mode dial is set to one of: Program, Shutter-priority, Aperture-priority, or Manual exposure mode. From page 78 of the [D5500 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/ETOYI00bfdW602XchPU57r5bLc70/D5500RM_(En)03.pdf),

> Note that AF-S and AF-C are available only in modes P, S, A, and M.